# Use JSON_TABLE cross join on subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I am at a loss on how to use a JSON_TABLE in mysql 8.0 only on a small part of another table, if the selection of this part involves a JOIN or a subquery:

Let's start with a table `predictions` which contains the value of a predictions as well as some foreign key

```
SELECT * FROM predictions

id | ml_model_id | value
+--+-------------+------ 
1  | 1           | [{"class": "dog", "confidence": 1}, {"class": "cat", "confidence": 0.03}]
```

Here is the selection of the whole table that works well:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM predictions,
         JSON_TABLE(
             predictions.value,
              "$[*]" 
              COLUMNS (class VARCHAR(30) PATH "$.class",
                       confidence FLOAT PATH "$.confidence")
            ) myjson
```

### Original problem: a subquery cannot be used as a table to build the JSON_TABLE on

However, this does not work anymore if I replace the `predictions` table by a subquery of it

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM predictions
    WHERE ml_model_id = 1
    # Do any type of filtering here, or even none at all
    ) preds,
    JSON_TABLE(
        preds.value,
        "$[*]"
        COLUMNS (class VARCHAR(30) PATH "$.class",
                       confidence FLOAT PATH "$.confidence")
            ) myjson
        )
```

I will get an SQL Error 1210 "Incorrect argument to JSON_TABLE"

### Limited workaround: If the filtering is on a table column, you can use WHERE...

My first thought was to take the filtering outside of the subquery, which to a certain extent work:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions, 
    JSON_TABLE(...) myjson
WHERE predictions.ml_model_id = 1
```

This solution works, already comes off as unelegant to me, because it means that the `,` between `predictions` and `JSON_TABLE` is an implicit lateral join instead of a cross join (Edit: note that even when using a `CROSS JOIN` instead of the `,` does an implicit lateral join)

### ...But it does not work if your filtering involves JOINs

However, if instead of a WHERE i'd want to filter by using a JOIN, I will get an even more cryptic error:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions, 
    JSON_TABLE(...) myjson
   INNER JOIN ml_models
       ON ml_models.id = predictions.ml_model_id
       AND ml_models.usage = "classification"
```

will raise an `SQL ERROR [1054] Unknown column 'predictions.ml_model_id' in 'on clause'`... Why would this column not be found ? Running without the inner join actually returns it !

### Unelegant workaround that seems to work in all cases: Using EXISTS in WHERE clause

Simply replacing the `INNER JOIN` by a `WHERE EXISTS` works, but this is really counterintuitive to work that way.

```
SELECT * FROM predictions, 
    JSON_TABLE(...) myjson
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ml_models
       WHERE ml_models.id = predictions.ml_model_id
       AND ml_models.usage = "classification")
```

Is there something that I don't understand on JSON_TABLE that prevents me to use a subquery on it ?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time if you are going to downvote people for answering them.

Comment: You previously deleted answer only reformulated one workaround that I already found without explaining neither why it worked nor why it was different.
  
I have reformulated my text to make clear that only the sentence ending with a "?" is a question, event though with a long-winded context on what I have already tried.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, it appears to be an order of operations when it comes to the joins.

```
SELECT * FROM predictions preds
   INNER JOIN ml_models
       ON ml_models.id = preds.ml_model_id
       AND ml_models.usage = "classification", 
    JSON_TABLE(preds.value, ...) myjson
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work with a subquery as first part of the join, by casting the JSON field as a JSON again in the JSON_TABLE

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM predictions
    WHERE ml_model_id = 1
    # Do any type of filtering here, or even none at all
    ) preds,
    JSON_TABLE(
        CAST(preds.value AS JSON),
        "$[*]"
        COLUMNS (class VARCHAR(30) PATH "$.class",
                       confidence FLOAT PATH "$.confidence")
            ) myjson
        )
```

I am however even more at a loss on why this would work, so I will keep the question open if someone has an explanation about *why* it works this way and not without the cast.